# error and delay on background fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery

this code is giving me an error, on mouse hover it shows a delay on the background change and i really dont know what its the problem. does anyone know what the problem is?

```
$('#compareDiv').hover(
     function(){
         $(this).data( $(this).css('background') );
         $(this).fadeOut().css('background', 'url(images/compare-V1.png) bottom left no-repeat' ).fadeIn();  
     },

     function(){ 
       $(this).fadeOut().css('background', $(this).data('background') ).fadeIn(); 

     } );
```

[check this out](http://anetdesign.com/patricia/martin-ebay/V1/index-V1.html#)

Answer (score 0):

What is it you are trying to do? One of the problems is that the fadeOut() method is asynchronous.  This means, you will have to provide a callback in order to execute a function after the animation has completed.  Your css background is getting set as soon as the animation is started.  Also, since you chain the fadeIn() right after the fadeOut(), it is probably creating some weird results.  You need to provide callbacks to the animation methods like this:

```
$(this).fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'url(images/compare-V1.png) bottom left no-repeat');
    $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

The other problem you're going to run into is if the user hovers in and hovers out really quickly the animations are going to queue up.  What I would recommend is using a brief delay before starting the animation, and cancelling the timeout if the user hovers out quickly.

Comment: am trying to change the background image on hover with the fade effect.. i wonder if u have an easy way to do it? someone told me the problem i have is am calling the same fuction in two staments, but i have no idea what is that really mean am very new in js coding.. any help will be so helful!